# Android app how to load /vendor/lib64/libname.so

Tags: java, android, kotlin, lib, android-app-bundle

I always hit below error

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library
> "/vendor/lib64/libname.so" not found

the lib create by myself with NDK build

I add below code in MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
init {
    val libPath = "/vendor/lib64/libname.so"

    System.load(libPath)
}
```

Comment: `/vendor` is a path that is not writable by users, so you can not install your library there and thus not load it fromm that path,